# Can't access the window level variable even though it exists. returns undefined when accessed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the window level variable in my script in the `window.onLoad()`, but it always returns `undefined`. But when I console log it or try to just type in the `window` in the debug console, it clearly shows me the variable exists on `window` object and has a value. I am unclear why this is happening and is there a way to access it? Please correct me if I am doing something wrong and point me in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: The `window._vp` variable is declared in the script of some live website and I am trying to access that particular variable using my chrome extension.

My script:

```
window.onload = _ => {
    console.log("window._vp is:", window._vp);
}
```

Website script:

```
var _vp = {};
_vp['IsDashAvailable'] = false;
//...
```

You can see the behavior in the following screenshot of the dev tool console:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Some contextual code would be helpful. Is _vp something you attach to window? is it defined before you console.log it?

Comment: *"But when I console log it...it clearly shows me the variable exists"* - Where are you calling `console.log()` from such that it works?

Comment: @RyanAmundson Yes, by looking at the website scripts, the _vp is attached to the window.

Comment: can we see the code?

Comment: @nnnnnn It's not working on `window.onLoad`, but does work when I do it in the dev tools console. And also, I tried to `console.log` inside the `setInterval` and also inside the `setTimeout`, but still, I was getting `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with your extensions isolated context, as detailed in another [SO post about Context isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script) who also faced an identical issue.

You should try the following Method quoted from the other answer:

### Method 2b: Using a function

For a big chunk of code, quoting the string is not feasible. Instead of using an array, a function can be used, and stringified:

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    // All code is executed in a local scope.
    // For example, the following does NOT overwrite the global `alert` method
    var alert = null;
    // To overwrite a global variable, prefix `window`:
    window.alert = null;
} + ')();';

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();
```

This method works, because the + operator on strings and a function converts all objects to a string. If you intend on using the code more than once, it's wise to create a function to avoid code repetition. An implementation might look like:

```
function injectScript(func) {
    var actualCode = '(' + func + ')();'
    ...
}
injectScript(function() {
   alert("Injected script");
});
```

Note: Since the function is serialized, the original scope, and all bound properties are lost!

```
var scriptToInject = function() {
    console.log(typeof scriptToInject);
};
injectScript(scriptToInject);
// Console output:  "undefined"
```